# if $f(x)=g(x)$ when $|x-a|<\lambda$,prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> suppose there is a $\lambda>0$  such that $f(x)=g(x)$ when $|x-a|<\lambda$.prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

my attempt:

i think i find an easy proof which is : if $lim_{ x\to a} f(x)=l$

then that's means  for every $\epsilon $ >0,there is a $\lambda' >0 $ such that if $0<|x-a|<\lambda'$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$,and because we care just about x's in ($a-\lambda $,$a+\lambda $ ) we can assume $\lambda ' <\lambda$,and in that interval we have $f(x)=g(x)$ .so if $0<|x-a|<\lambda'$ then $|f(x)-l|=|g(x)-l|<\epsilon$ which  means that if  $\lim_{ x\to a} f(x)=l$ then $\lim_{ x\to a} g(x)=l$ and also if  $\lim_{ x\to a} g(x)=l$ then $\lim_{ x\to a} f(x)=l$.
so finally: $\lim_{ x\to a} g(x)= \lim_{ x\to a} f(x)$.

**-is my proof right ?**

Comment: Yes essentially right.  To be a bit technical, it doesn't necessarily follow that $\lambda' < \lambda$; however, you can choose the appropriate bound in the limit definition of $g$ to be the lesser of $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$.

Comment: but if $\lambda ' >\lambda$ ,then we can't say  $f(x)=g(x)$!!,

Comment: Indeed.  The fact that $f(x) = g(x)$ on $|x-a|<\lambda$ doesn't in itself imply that $\lambda' < \lambda$.  It means we want to *choose* $\lambda'$ such that it is less than $\lambda$ (and we are free to do so).

Comment: but if we choose $ \lambda ' >\lambda$ we can't use the hypothesis $f(x)=g(x)$ in our proof ,so the proof will not depend on this hypothesis ,i don't know if you understand me,but anyway you can post the answer( in case of $\lambda '>\lambda$ )

Comment: I think you've essentially got it (having changed the language to *we can assume* $\lambda' < \lambda$).

Comment: yeah i know that $f(x)=g(x)$ on $|x-a|<\lambda $ does'nt imply that $ \lmabda '<\lambda$,just my problem is my terrible english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here is the way I would phrase your proof.

Let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = l$.  From the limit definition there exists a value $\lambda'$ such that, for *any* $\epsilon > 0$:

$$
|f(x) - l| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad |x-a| < \lambda'. 
$$

*Define* $\delta = \min\{\lambda, \lambda'\}$.  Then for any given $\epsilon$, we have
$$
|g(x) - l| = |f(x) - l| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad |x-a| < \delta.
$$
(Note that this line required that $|x-a| < \lambda$ *and* that $|x-a|<\lambda'$, which is why $\delta$ is defined as above.)
Thus $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = l$.

Comment: thank you ......